# Expected value and Time function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> You are conducting interviews.
>
> If the candidate is **qualified** it takes **30 minutes** to interview the candidate.
>
> If the candidate is **not qualified** it takes **10 minutes** to interview the candidate.
>
> **a) Create a function for this scenario**,
>
> **b) then calculate the expected value. The mean is 17.**

My best guess on the formula is T = 30y + 10z.

I know this does not work with calculating the expected value because the `z` needs to be `y` to do an expected value calculation. Can I please have some ideas with this?

Comment: hint: can't you substitude z with (1-y)? you can't be both qualified and not qualified at the same time after all ;)

Comment: Can you explain why you plug in 1-y? What happens if you interview 5 unqualified people and 2 qualified people?

Comment: being qualified or not is a probability. since you cant be both at the same time you are to y% qualified and to (100-y)% not qualified. Or to simply remove the % sign, just say 0<y<1 and z=1-y

Comment: And you plug the 1- y into the z because it's smaller right?

Comment: actually it doesnt matter which variable you substitude with which. The point is: y=1-z AND z=1-y (simple equation solving). The only thing that's for sure is, that 0<y<1, because otherwise the **mean** would be 10 or 30

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the probability that the candidate is qualified. Then, the expected time for an interview would be

$$ \mathbb E[T] = p 30 + (1-p)10. $$

Therefore, if $ \mathbb E[T] = 17 $, it must be that

$$ p 30 + (1-p)10 = 17 $$

which implies that

$$ p = 7/20.$$

Comment: Can you explain why you plug in 1-p? What happens if you interview 5 unqualified people and 2 qualified people?

Comment: @cokedude Then $p = 2/7$.

Comment: @mzp p doesnt change that significant in 7 tries. (assuming an almost endless supply of interviewees)